# SELECT WHERE difference between now and a timestamp is less than 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, where-clause

I want to make a MySQL selection where the difference between NOW() and a timestamp in the table is less than a specific period of time, like 24 hours.  I've tried doing subtraction but it hasn't worked and DateDiff isn't what I want.  There must be a simple way to do this, but I can't figure it out.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
   timestampdiff(HOUR, yourtimestampcolumn, now() ) as hours_since,
   *
FROM 
   Your_table 
WHERE 
   timestampdiff(HOUR, yourtimestampcolumn, now() ) < 24
```

Refer 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: thanks, it's actually going to be   timestampdiff(hour, yourtimestampcolumn, now()) < 24, otherwise it will return a negative number and without quotes around hour

Comment: @george Corrected, thanks for the heads up, and for the accept.